# Calculating tension in a winch cable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I have the question:

[image]

Here is my attempt is this correct ?

[image]

(I would put this question on physics SE however every question I have put up so far is apparently "not related to physics" and is a "homework question")

Comment: No.  Tension does not equal weight or else the mass would not be accelerating upward.

Comment: I have solved part i) (2403.45) and part ii) (2502.43), which I was told just now is correct however I am not sure how to do part iii)

Comment: Nothing of what you are trying is working. Just give it up already.

Comment: Why should I give it up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key concepts:

- Newton's first law
- Newton's second law
- If $a$ is uniform (/constant), then $a = \dfrac{v_f-v_i}{t}$

At rest: $$\sum F = T - mg = 0 \\ T = mg$$

Going up: $$\sum F = T - mg = ma \\ T = m(a+g) = m\left(\frac{v_f-v_i}{t}+g\right)$$

Going down: $$\sum F = mg - T = ma \\ T = m(g-a) = m\left(g-\frac{v_f-v_i}{t}\right)$$